How to bypass pipe detection?
A question at stackoverflow has answers that show the following way of detecting if standard output is a pipe:
if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo terminal; else echo "not a terminal"; fi

The -t flag is described by man pages as "True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal."
Is there a way to bypass this detection in order to preserve color in commands that omit it upon detection of a pipe?

One possible use is for piping colored output to less -R. Another is for saving readable logs. Another is for piping it into an ANSI escape sequence parser, which can then recreate the formatting in some other format (e.g. HTML or wikitext).

Yes, but normally you should file a bug to the program (to force colour if you want, and the same to avoid displaying colours). So the answer is yes, but sorry, I do not remember the command. It was an utility program (a very tiny screen/tmux, mostly to check how programs interact with console). If I found, I would answer.
